# use SolutionName in c#

Tags: c#, msbuild, solution

How can I use project properties (from the MSBuild environment) like SolutionName in c# code?

I want to create a kind of template in C# code where I need to reference the name of the current solution. In Wix for example I would use $(var.SolutionName). Is there any solution in C#?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no built-in property in MSBuild that would resolve to solution name. There are few properties that would resolve to project name and path though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85ccbadc-87e4-4002-8d9e-289461fe1cfa/get-current-solution-name?forum=csharpgeneral) can be helpful. I didn't test it but it seems it works.

EDIT

Try this:

```
String solutionName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: On the same line--> [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)